# Простой скрипт (jQuery), разворачивающий блок полностью по клику

Tags: jquery

Всем добрый день.

**Задача была такая**:
Есть фильтр, у которого каждый элемент фильтра имеет много характеристик. Нужно сделать так, чтобы по-умолчанию открывалось 6 характеристик, остальные скрывались под ссылкой "Показать еще". При нажатии на ссылку, всплывали бы и они.

Собственно, задача не самая сложная, сделал я топорный вариант:

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('#mse2_filters fieldset').children('.filter__ul').each(function(){
        if (jQuery(this).height() > 144) {
            jQuery(this).css('height', '144px');
        } else {
            jQuery(this).next('.btn-filter_showhide').hide();
        }
    });

});

jQuery('.btn-filter_showhide').on('click', function() {
    var filterul = jQuery(this).prev('.filter__ul');
    if (filterul.css('height') == '144px') {
    jQuery(this).text('Скрыть');
    filterul.height('auto').show('slow');
} else {
    jQuery(this).text('Показать еще…');
    filterul.animate({height: "144px"}, 300);
}
});
```

В двух словах: Первая запись перебирает все группы фильтров, оценивает их высоту (144 пикселя соответствует 6 характеристикам), если больше 144, то появляется ссылка "Показать еще".
Ну а вторая запись работает с кликом.

И он у меня работает без проблем. Однако, в Хроме на другом компьютере, ссылка не отрабатывает ну никак. Консоль браузера ошибок не выдает.
Как думаете, в чем может быть проблема? Версия Хрома актуальная, остальные скрипты на сайте работают.

Теоретически, могли бы как-то модули КриптоПро повлиять на срабатывание скрипта? Или антивирус.. или еще что-то в системе?

Comment: пропишите в `html` 2 `div` один видимый, а второй не видимый, и показывайте второй по нажатию кнопки ну или ссылки

Comment: Хотите сказать, что это будет проще, чем скрывать блок до определенной высоты, а потом просто убирать ограничение?

Сам по себе вариант нормальный, вот только скрипт магазина выводит фильтры в списках. Каждый фильтр - один список, элементы списка - характеристики.

Comment: Смысл в том, что они все у вас будут на странице, прост в `display:none`, пока вы по нажатию кнопки не сделаете `display:block`

Comment: Не к пикселям привязываться, а к индексам элементов. Вы ведь знаете, что их должно быть шесть: `.each(function(index)`.